# convert 3d model into stl

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, stl

I am new to Blender and still learning, but I have a problem while I am using Blender and exporting the problem to stl for 3d printing. I face a problem in that the slicer needs to define the part correctly. It has a lot of parts that need to be added, as shown in the attached images. I don't know what the reason and how I should solve it. I tried the add-on 3d print tool, but I got a lot of non-manifold also

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/4306/mY0Uza.jpg]

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/6775/SaRNkY.jpg]

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/152/2JVgHB.jpg]

Comment: I can't say exactly from the screenshot where the problems in your mesh are, but just seeing that there are 34,515 non-manifold edges makes me think the mesh needs a lot of reworking...

Comment: Thank you for replying, i draw this object on fusion 360 and now wanna use blender to convert it to stl file I don't know if the blender can fix it automatically or I must do it manually